# sql -Extract the second key in a json string

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have some tables that contains the payment details of students. In one of the tables, a column collects data in json string.
I want to extract the value of amount from the string below. However, you would notice that key 1 has `amount` and key 2 has `amount` too.

After extracting amount, I'm obviously getting the values for the two keys, but I want to extract only the amount value in key 2

```
{"1":{"amount":"500","date":"2023-01-06","amount_discount":"5500","amount_fine":"0","description":"","collected_by":"Super Admin(356)","payment_mode":"Cash","received_by":"1","inv_no":1},
"2":{"amount":"49500","date":"2023-01-22","amount_discount":"0","amount_fine":"0","description":"Being payment for tuition only","collected_by":"Juliet OLAJIDE(S20170181)","payment_mode":"bank_transfer","received_by":"32","inv_no":2}}
```

Below is my query:

```
SELECT student_fees_master.*,JSON_EXTRACT(student_fees_deposite.amount_detail, '$.*.amount') AS `deposit` 
FROM `student_fees_master` 
INNER JOIN fee_session_groups on fee_session_groups.id = student_fees_master.fee_session_group_id 
INNER JOIN fee_groups_feetype on  fee_groups_feetype.fee_session_group_id = fee_session_groups.id
INNER JOIN fee_groups on fee_groups.id=fee_groups_feetype.fee_groups_id 
INNER JOIN feetype on feetype.id=fee_groups_feetype.feetype_id 
LEFT JOIN student_fees_deposite on
student_fees_deposite.student_fees_master_id=student_fees_master.id 
and student_fees_deposite.fee_groups_feetype_id=fee_groups_feetype.id
WHERE fee_groups_feetype.feetype_id=1
```

This is what I'm getting:
`["500", "49500"]`

But I want this:
`["49500"]`

How do I go about this?

Comment: yes it's MySQL. ```$.amount``` give me NULL

Comment: In this case you could probably do `$."2".amount`. That doesn't look for the second one, but uses the fact that the key is literally 2, so maybe worse (or better) than the answer provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows :

```
with cte as (
select '{"1":{"amount":"500","date":"2023-01-06","amount_discount":"5500","amount_fine":"0","description":"","collected_by":"Super Admin(356)","payment_mode":"Cash","received_by":"1","inv_no":1},
        "2":{"amount":"49500","date":"2023-01-22","amount_discount":"0","amount_fine":"0","description":"Being payment for tuition only","collected_by":"Juliet OLAJIDE(S20170181)","payment_mode":"bank_transfer","received_by":"32","inv_no":2}}' as deposit
)
select JSON_EXTRACT(deposit->"$.*", "$[1].amount") AS `deposit`
from cte;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/V8TZarRP)

Comment: How would this work because I have a lot of data in the table. The json string I used as example is just one out of hundreds

Comment: instead of `JSON_EXTRACT(student_fees_deposite.amount_detail, '$.*.amount')` use `JSON_EXTRACT(student_fees_deposite.amount_detail->"$.*", "$[1].amount")`

Comment: yes, I like this better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution might be like this:

`ORDER BY deposit DESC LIMIT 1`